# In excel, how to calculate range with maximum numbers falling inside it?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have this data set in excel column; I want to find where most of the data was clouded e.g. around 100 values of this set fell between 2018.5 to 2020.5 But it is manual work. What can be the formula for searching these value. I tried using Average & Std. Deviation but they have some flaws & not always accurate. And the range must be as narrow as possible, say if I have total number of values in the set equal to 150 then more than 60%-70% i.e 90-105 of these values should come under that determined range.

```
2025
2023.75
2023
2020.15
2020.3
2018.35
2017.5
2017.95
2016
2019.45
2020
2022.4
2022.25
2018.2
2018.05
2019.3
2022
2021.45
2021.45
2019.8
2020
2019.25
2019.35
2019.85
2019.4
2018.25
2019.55
2020
2020
2020.05
2020
2020
2021
2019.8
2019.8
2020
2020.05
2019.9
2021
2019.1
2019.1
2015.5
2015.5
2018.5
2017.25
2018.85
2018.85
2018.85
2017.05
2019
2020.05
2020
2020
2020
2019.7
2019.65
2019.65
2020
2019
2018.05
2020
2019.4
2020
2020.05
2017.4
2020
2020
2020
2019.95
2019.95
2019.95
2018
2019.85
2019.85
2019.7
2020
2020
2020
2020
2020
2019.75
2019.6
2019.75
2019.75
2019.95
2019.95
2019.95
2020
2020
2020
2020
2019.35
2019.35
2019.95
2019.95
2020
2019.95
2020
2020
2020
2021.7
2020
2021
2020
2020
2020
2020
2019.95
2020
2019.85
2019.8
2019
2019.8
2019.8
2019.8
2020
2019.9
2019.9
2020
2020
2019.8
2019.3
2019.85
2020
2019.1
2018
2017.5
2015.05
2009
2008
2011.5
2011
2011
2014.65
2011
2010
2009.05
2005.65
2005
1998.1
2000
1999
2001.7
2000.95
2002
2005
2006.7
2004.4
2004.85
2006.8
2007.45
2006
2010
2012.5
2012.2
2008.8
2007.4
2007.55
2005.35
2005.4
2006.9
2008.05
2003.85
2002.6
2004.85
2002.35
2006
2006
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want... having range and amount variable, there is nothing to search for... if you are searching for the smallest range which fits to 70% of the values that would be different...

Comment: i dont understand yr question. are you looking for normal distribution of the data ?

Comment: @Dirk - yeah it will be helpful if you can provide solution for smallest range which fits to 70% of the values.

Comment: @Erik - no, not normal distribution just looking for the two values where most of the data is concentrated like between 2018.5 to 2020.5 in my data set.

Comment: may be data with the highest occurrence, I can use MODE function but there are some problems with it like it will treat 2020.00 & 2020.05 differently but actually there is a very little percentage difference between them that's why it may mislead.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What you desire isn't possible with the worksheet functions as they are. you would need to create a table (having one dimension as lower cut and one dimension with upper cut to delete the lowest/highest till you got your range... but you would need to do so every time the size changes (and the formulas would be.... don't think about it...</strike> (still assuming you need the whole range)

You can do it by formula: (all Values in A:A)

```
C1:  0.7 (at least x % values need to be included / 1 = 100%)
C2:  =MAX(IF(MIN(SMALL(A:A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))-1)-SMALL(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))))=(SMALL(A:A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))-1)-SMALL(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1)))),SMALL(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))),0))
C3:  =MAX(IF(MIN(SMALL(A:A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))-1)-SMALL(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))))=(SMALL(A:A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))-1)-SMALL(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1)))),SMALL(A:A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*(1-C1),0)+1))-1)))
```

> Formulas in `C2/C3` are array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

`C2` will show the lower value and `C3` the upper one. You can get the number of values used with `=COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")` and the count of numbers in the calculation with `=ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")*C1,0)`.

---

But there is still the way to do so with a UDF like this:
Open up the VBA-window (hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). Then click at "Insert" and then "Module". Copy/paste the code below into your Module.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getValRange(rng As Range, amountVal As Double) As String
  Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

  Dim cellsVal As Variant
  Dim cellsCount As Long

  For Each cellsVal In rng.Value
    If IsNumeric(cellsVal) And Len(cellsVal) > 0 Then cellsCount = cellsCount + 1
  Next

  Dim cellsNow As Long
  cellsNow = cellsCount
  cellsVal = rng.Value
  amountVal = amountVal / 100

  Dim AverageVal As Double
  Dim maxVal As Double
  Dim minVal As Double
  Dim valToDel As Double

  Dim x As Long, y As Long

  While (cellsNow / cellsCount) > amountVal

    AverageVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(cellsVal)
    maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(cellsVal)
    minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(cellsVal)

    If (maxVal - AverageVal) > (AverageVal - minVal) Then
      valToDel = maxVal
    Else
      valToDel = minVal
    End If

    For x = 1 To UBound(cellsVal)
      For y = 1 To UBound(cellsVal, 2)

        If cellsVal(x, y) = valToDel Then
          cellsVal(x, y) = ""
          Exit For
        End If

      Next y
    Next x

    cellsNow = cellsNow - 1
  Wend

  maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(cellsVal)
  minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(cellsVal)

  getValRange = minVal & " - " & maxVal

End Function
```

Then simply put in the cell something like this:

```
=getValRange(A1:A150,70)
```

to get the lowest and the highest values as string like `2018.2 - 2021`. (calculated for your numbers)

It simply checks for the value having the highest difference to the average and then excludes it. Repeating this till the number of cells is less or equal to the set percentage. However, going for a percentage lower then 50% it may fail. For cases like this you would need something like "brute force" (which may have long calculation-times)

---

To get the best solution for a set amount of values, you can use this:

```
Public Function getValRange(rng As Range, amountVal As Double) As String
  If rng.Cells.Count < 2 Or amountVal <= 0 Or amountVal >= 100 Then Exit Function

  Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

  Dim cellsVal As Variant
  Dim allVal() As Variant
  ReDim allVal(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
  Dim i As Long

  'get all values in in 1d-array
  For Each cellsVal In rng.Value
    If IsNumeric(cellsVal) And Len(cellsVal) > 0 Then
      i = i + 1
      allVal(i) = cellsVal
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve allVal(1 To i)

  'sort 1d-array
  For i = 2 To UBound(allVal)
    If allVal(i) < allVal(i - 1) Then
      cellsVal = allVal(i)
      allVal(i) = allVal(i - 1)
      allVal(i - 1) = cellsVal
      i = 1
    End If
  Next

  'get value count to be used
  amountVal = Application.RoundUp((UBound(allVal) / 100) * amountVal, 0)

  Dim clsrange(1) As Variant
  'get the closest range
  clsrange(0) = allVal(amountVal) - allVal(1)
  clsrange(1) = allVal(1) & " - " & allVal(amountVal)
  For i = 2 To UBound(allVal) - amountVal
    If (allVal(amountVal + i - 1) - allVal(i)) < clsrange(0) Then
      clsrange(0) = allVal(amountVal + i - 1) - allVal(i)
      clsrange(1) = allVal(i) & " - " & allVal(amountVal + i - 1)
    End If
  Next

  getValRange = clsrange(1)

End Function
```

---

A completely different approach would be using the sort option. Lets assume the columns `B:E` are empty. Copy column `A` to `B` and then sort column `B`.
Get the amound of cells you want to check for (lets say 50 for now). In `C1` you put `=B50-B1` in `D1` `=B1` and in `D1` comes `=B50`. And then copy it down till it reaches the range with empty cells (having 150 cells, will end at `C101`, autofill simply `C1:E1` downs till column `E` starts to get empty). Now for column `C` use conditional formatting with the formula `=C1=MIN(C:C)`... then check for the formatted cell, it will tell you the smallest range having the min and max in column `D` and `E`.

Comment: thanks a lot mate for sharing this code. It is amazing. Solves 90% of my problem.

Comment: @MehulPatel what are the missing 10%?